# Passing data array to funcion Angular 5

Tags: angular, typescript, angular5

i'm new on Angular 5.
I have a function like this

```
this.login(credentials);
```

i need to pass username and password fetched from webservice in this array in this array. In php i do this:

```
$credentials = array(['username'=> $response.user.username, 'password'=> $response.user.password]);
```

how i can obtain the same result in Angular5?

Comment: you want  to pass in the function or fetch data from a function in angular code ?

Comment: Impressive. Please tell me, how did you enable dot notation (`$response.user.username`) in PHP? Is it version specific?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Maybe you can use an object.

```
var credentials= {username:"Blabla", password:"Blabla"};
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try this :

```
interface User{
    username : string ;
    password : string ;
}

private credentials : User[] = [] ;
```

in your service :

```
credentials.push({username : response.user.username  , password:response.user.password})
```

Answer (score -1):

You can not have string indices in JavaScript/TypeScript, but you can use an object to store your credential data.

```
this.credentials = {
    username: response.user.username,
    password: response.user.password
}
```

Assuming that response has a property user which has username and password.

You can then access these values like this

```
this.credentials.username
this.credentials.password
```